# Query date in CQL

Tags: cql

I want to run an CQL query in Cassansdra DB by limiting the result by date, when i run a simple query without filtering i get the below result:

```
select * from bssapi.call_detail_records where subscription_id = '116377120' and year = 2020 and month = 3;
```

The result which i get is the below:

```
subscription_id | year | month | event_at                 | id                             | account_unit_type | b_number   | balance_after | balance_before | balance_id | basic_service_code | billable_amount | billable_unit | billing_item__code | call_case | call_destination | call_destination_type | cell_id  | created_at               | customer_id | data_amount | dc_event    | direction_type | duration | event_type | invoice_sequence_id | lac  | mcc | msisdn     | network_code | product_code | reference_price | roaming_indicator | service_category | service_type | subscription_type | technical_call_case | total_with_vat | transaction_amount
-----------------+------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+------------+---------------+----------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------------+----------+--------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------+------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------
       XXXXXXXX | 2020 |     3 | 2020-03-01 07:45:51+0000 | POSTPAIDÿ3489472270ÿ2020-03-01 |                 0 | XXXXXXXX |           0.0 |            0.0 |       null |                 11 |              60 |       seconds |           BNATCALL |         0 |              066 |              national |     2730 | 2020-03-01 07:58:48+0000 |   XXXXXXXXXX|           0 | CALLNAT600R |            MOC |       16 |       CALL |             3626608 | 0A2A | 603 | XXXXXXXXX |        DZAOT |         null |             5.0 |                 0 |             null |            1 |          XXXXXXX|                1011 |            0.0 |                0.0
```

What i want is to get the result only for one day, for example the result only for today "2020-03-19 07:45:51+0000", i tried several query but i am not able to get a correct result, for example i tried the below:

```
select * from bssapi.call_detail_records where subscription_id = '116377120' and created_at > '2020-03-19 00:00:00' allow filtering;
```

The error returned is:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Partition key part year must be restricted since preceding part is"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I think you just need to provide your requirement for the field **event_at** like this:

```
select * 
from bssapi.call_detail_records 
where subscription_id = '116377120' 
and year = 2020 
and month = 3
and event_at = '2020-03-19 07:45:51+0000';
```

Comment: It's working fine thanks, now i want to get the count(*), when i am lunching the below query: 
`
select count(*)  from bssapi.call_detail_records  WHERE  year = 2020  and month = 3 and event_at > '2020-03-01 07:45:51+0000' ;
`

Comment: i am getting this error : 
`
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Partitioning column "year" cannot be restricted because the preceding column (
"ColumnDefinition{name=subscription_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=0, inde
xName=null, indexType=null}") is either not restricted or is restricted by a non-EQ relation"
`

Comment: But when i user the filter by subscription_id, the count is given correctly

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for that, so that the title matches your issue and other people can help you there as well. 

This question of yours here is resolved, so can you please accept my answer by ticking the checkmark? Thank you :)